# Sparse and dense array in C

Tags: c

How can I print a sparse and a dense array? 
More exactly, if I have an array with pozitions :

```
> (pozition, value) = [(2,4)(3,5),(4,5)] must print
> [(0,0)(1,0)(2,4)(3,5)(4,5)]?
```

or If have an array `[[(0,0)(1,0)(2,4)(3,5)(4,5)]`should print`[(2,4)(3,5),(4,5)]`?
I started with the structure:

```
struct arr
{
    int position;
    int value;
    struct arr *next;
};
```

And for given values and position how should I do? I tried to print, works, but I don't know if is is correct.

```
typedef struct arr *ARR;

ARR term(int poz, int val)
{
    ARR w;
    w=(ARR)malloc(sizeof(struct arr));
    w->position=poz;
    w->value=val;
    return w;
}

ARR oneterm(int val,int poz, ARR nextarr) ///create term
{
    ARR w;
    w=term(poz,val;
    w->next =nextarr;
    return w;
}
ARR create(int poz[],int val[],int n)
{
    ARR w=NULL;
    for(n--;n>=0;n--)
        w=oneterm(poz[n],val[n],w);
    return w;
}
void print(struct arr p, char *text)
{
    printf("\n%s",text);
    for(; p; p=p->next)
    printf("(%d , %d)",p->value,p->position);
}
```

This is what I have in main:

```
ARR a=NULL;
int c[] = {2,7,11,12};
int b[]= {4,3,1,0};
a=createvect(b,c,4);
```

My question is: how to print a sparse and a dense array?

Comment: `p->urm`? Please post real code.

Comment: `struct arr p` should be `struct arr *p`.

Comment: I added more from my work. I'm sorry that I omitted some details!

Comment: It would be nice to complete your code snippet with a `main` function, which calls your functions and the expected output of the complete program.

Comment: I would solve three separate tasks. 1) Transformation into a dense list. 2) Transformation into a sparse list. 3) Just print the list.

Comment: What I expect, I wrote, how can I print the dense/sparse array, the result after I called functions is : (4,2)(3,7)(1,11)(0,12)

Comment: @freestyle How I can do those transformations?

Comment: I was thinking to take a 'for' from 0 to maximum of positions and where p->value not exists, put 0?

Comment: The first of all, you should to concretize what does mean sparse and dense array/list?
Your example, just example. You should define in mathematical sense.

Comment: That's the reason I asked. To understand how works.

Answer (score 0):

The two problems are similar, but the second is easier to implement. Both can be done in linear time.

---

The second problem:

```
[(0,0), (1,0), (2,4), (3,5), (4,5)] -> [(2,4), (3,5), (4,5)]
```

Simply iterate the input list and output the pairs for which the second element is non-zero.

---

The first problem:

```
[(2,4), (3,5), (4,5)] -> [(0,0), (1,0), (2,4), (3,5), (4,5)]
```

Let's assume the input list is always ordered and that the output list should go from `0` to the maximum first element of the input list.

Create a loop that keeps an index starting at `0` and, at the same time, iterate through the list. If the index matches the one in the list, output that one and advance in the list. Otherwise, output a pair with a zero as the second element. Stop when you find the end of the list.